# SQLAlchemy - Query parent by its childer, filter a join to match every children in a list

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to query a Person who has all of the requested Skills. Not sure what is the best way to build the query dynamically.

ORM Objects are below. Many-to-many between Person and Skills, connecting table not included here:

```
Person
name=John, skills=[Skill(id=1)] # John knows Python
name=Eve, skills=[Skill(id=1), Skill(id=2)] # Eve knows Python and SQLAlchemy

Skill
id=1, name=Python
id=2, name=SQLAlchemy
id=3, name=Social skills
```

On a search page user selects one or many skills and a search result of Persons is created based on this. Let's say an user wants to find a person who knows Python and also SQLAlchemy. Application gets a list of two ids from the form submit, [1, 2]. I got the following query to kind of work, to find the persons with matching skills:

```
session.query(Person)./
join(Skill, Person.skills).filter(Skill.id.in_(list_of_skill_ids))
```

However, using the in_ clause causes John person to be found as he has one of the required skills. But the search result should only show persons who have all of the requested skills. Basically what I want is something like in_() but which user *and* instead of *or* to match the id list. I probably should replace the in_() part with this, which does not take the id list directly:

```
filter(Person.id == 1, Person.id == 2)
```

But what is the easiest way to build the query programmatically using the the list of skill ids that I receive from the form? Number of ids can be 1..n. Or is this even the right way to query a parent by its children?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straight-forward SA solution is using the [`any`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any) for each skill:

```
list_of_skill_ids = [1, 2]
qry = session.query(Person)
for skill_id in list_of_skill_ids:
    qry = qry.filter(Person.skills.any(Skill.id == skill_id))

print('\n'.join("{}".format(_) for _ in qry.all()))
```

*This might not be the most performant query for large datasets, but it is very clean.*

Alternatively below should work too. (Similar to the answer of RedBaron, but puts the check directly in the query):

```
qry = (session.query(Person)
        .join(Skill, Person.skills)
        .filter(Skill.id.in_(list_of_skill_ids))
        .group_by(Person)
        .having(len(list_of_skill_ids) <= func.count(Skill.id))
    )

print('\n'.join("{}".format(_) for _ in qry.all()))
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach can be to find list of persons fulfilling *each* skill-set and then taking an intersection of all the lists. But the downside in this case is that if you have to search for 10 skill-sets you'll need to fire 10 queries.

A better approach is to group your original query by person ID and then count the number of skills for each person. Only keep people whose skill count matches count of your skill-sets. Maybe something like this?

```
skill_count = session.query(Person.id.label('id'),func.count(Skill.id.distinct()).label('scount')).\
              select_from(Person).\
              join(Person.skills).\
              filter(Skill.id.in_(list_of_skill_ids)).\
              group_by(Person.id).all()
matching_pid_list = [x.id for x in skill_count if x.scount == len(list_of_skill_ids)]
```